# I have 4 criteria which may or may not have values how do I write a procedure to fetch data according to this criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, conditional-statements

I have 4 criteria which may or may not have values how do I write a procedure to fetch data according to this criteria.

These criteria may have values or may have empty string. If they have empty string I need to completely eliminate the condition and fetch full data.

How do I do it in sql server.

Comment: Sounds like a query composed with if-statements. Does it have to be a stored procedure or can you compose the query in a programming language?

Comment: If any one parameter is provided whole search must fetch results depending on it and empty string values of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form is to create parameters with a default value such as NULL
and test as follows:

```
create procedure MyProc
(
    @param1 int = NULL,
    @param2 int = NULL
)
AS

SELECT
    <columnlist>
FROM
    <tablename>
WHERE
    (@param1 IS NULL OR SomeColumn = @param1) AND
    (@param2 IS NULL OR SomeColumn = @param2)
```

Just be aware that this can lead to unhelpful parameter sniffing especially with a large number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <Procedure_Name>
(
     @param1 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @param2 INT = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

     IF ((@param1 IS NOT NULL) AND (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@param1))) = 0))
     BEGIN
          SET @param1 = NULL
     END

     IF ((@param2 IS NOT NULL) AND (@param2 = -1))
     BEGIN
          SET @param2 = NULL
     END

     SELECT *
     FROM <Table_Name>
     WHERE (@param1 IS NULL OR Column_1 LIKE '%' + @param1 + '%'
     AND (@param2 IS NULL OR Column_2 = @param2)
END
```

PS: You can remove/modify INT validation as per your needs. I used to have this check because my application never sends a negative value for Id column, but only in case I can't send null for int datatype.

Comment: Thanks , What I dont know is, about the % operator.

Comment: % operator is a wild card search for matching partial text. 
Please accept the answer if it works for you.